# Excel SUMIFS Two Tables Criteria AND >= Comparisons

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two tables:

1. BOOKINGS BookingID Client
2. BOOKINGPAYMENTS BookingRange RangeStart RangeFinish Client Amount

When i input a String Range in Table 2 it automatically fills the RangeStart and RangeFinish fields, if its only one BookingID it puts same number in both.

I want to SUM all the amounts in Table 2 when client matches and when BookingID in Table 1 is greater or equals than RangeStart and lower or equals than RangeFinish in Table 2.

So far i have this:

```
SUMIFS(Table2[Amounts],Table2[Client],[Client],Table2[RangeStart],">="&[BookingID],Table2[RangeFinish],"<="&[BookingID])
```

It works correctly when the range contains only 1 number but when its eg. '2-4' it doesnt. I tried converting RangeStart & RangeFinish fields to numbers using VALUE() but isnt working either.

Any leads?

Answer (score 1):

I found out the problem was that i put the >=/<= signs backwards :)